# Adding tooltip to div with an overflow

Tags: html, css, tooltip, overflow, frontend

I'm developing a horizontal scrollable section with multiple listed items. Each listed item contains a tooltip that should display above said listed item on hover. Since the parent div is a scrollable section, I need the tooltip to be positioned relative to the listed items but this causes the tooltip to disappear due to the "overflow-x:scroll" set on the parent. I'm really stumped now. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroller">
   <div class="scrollable-item">
      <span> Static Text</span>
      <span> Static Text</span>
      <div class="scrollable-item-tooltip">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="scrollable-item">
      <span> Static Text</span>
      <span> Static Text</span>
      <div class="scrollable-item-tooltip">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="scrollable-item">
      <span> Static Text</span>
      <span> Static Text</span>
      <div class="scrollable-item-tooltip">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scroller {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.scrollable-item {
  position:relative;
  width:160px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.scrollable-item-tooltip {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
}
```

I tried creating a fiddle but it looks like there's something preventing me from breaking the layout so the code actually works fine on the link below without an overflow. I'll leave the link here anyway. 
https://jsfiddle.net/xjrkt2fe/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, content outside of your scrolling div will be hidden/clipped by the boundaries of the div.

Your options are to: 1) increase the size of the div to accommodate the tooltips (mostly likely not an option). or 2) add the tooltips somewhere outside the div and manually position them next to the items in the div on hover. This likely also includes handling collision with screen edges, handling updating the position as the div is scrolled, etc. You might be able to dodge that last issue if the tooltip can just hide on scroll.

Depending on what framework/library/etc. you're using, you might have something available to do some of that for you. If not, something like jQuery UI's .position() method or Tether http://github.hubspot.com/tether/ would be very handy for that.